# A vertical line separates matrix entries in the tikzpicture matrix environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, matrices, tikz-matrix

How do we make a perfect vertical line as the line in the square matrix to separate between
Cc and G on the left and the D and H on the right in the tikzpicture matrix environment?

The line shall be the best to set perfectly in mid way between Cc and G on the left and the D and H on the right.

I would like to stick to tikzpicture matrix environment if by all means possible.

Thank you for any suggestions/comments.

Here is my failed attempt.
[image]

Here is my Tex code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

    \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,mathtools}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=1pt,row sep=1em,column sep=1em] (M)
    {
     & A &  B & Cc & D \\
      & E &  F & G & H\\
    }
    ;
    \draw[ ->] (M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny ab};
    \draw[ ->] (M-1-3.east) -- (M-1-4.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny bc};
    \draw[-] (M-1-4.north east) -- (M-2-4.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Cc and G are not aligned right, whereas D and H are more-or-less aligned left, it's not possible to make it both vertical and have it halfway between both Cc and D and halfway between G and H without violating the laws of physics, which is too involved a project to address in an SE post. Instead, I take Cc and D as the reference points when finding the midway point, and G for the lower point. H is not used in the calculation.

You can use the `calc` library to find the point halfway between the two top nodes, create a marker coordinate and use the marker to hold the horizontal position when creating the line to the bottom.

[image: adjusted line]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=1pt,row sep=1em,column sep=1em] (M)
  {
    & A &  B & Cc & D \\
    & E &  F & G & H\\
  }
  ;
  \draw[ ->] (M-1-2.east) -- (M-1-3.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny ab};
  \draw[ ->] (M-1-3.east) -- (M-1-4.west) node[midway,above,pos=0.3]{\,\tiny bc};
  \draw[-] ($(M-1-4.north east)!.5!(M-1-5.north west)$) coordinate (a) -- (a |- M-2-4.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice! I voted up

Comment: "($(M-1-4.north east)!.5!(M-1-5.north west)$)" this is meant to find the mid point between 1-4 and 1-5. Namely between Cc and D

Comment: How about "coordinate (a) -- (a |- M-2-4.south)"? What does (a) here mean? What is  "(a |- M-2-4.south)"? (but note for the mark G at 2-4 while H at 2-5, so G is used??).

Comment: But you said "when finding the midway point, and H for the lower point. G is not used in the calculation." (but note for the mark G at 2-4 while H at 2-5, so G is used??)

Comment: @zeta (1) Yes. That's what loading the `calc` library allows. It's actually finding the midway point between the `north east` and `north west` anchors of `M-1-4` and `M-1-5` respectively. (2) `coordinate (a)` creates a coordinate at the current point on the path. (a |- M-2-4.south) is the point vertically aligned with `(a)` and horizontally aligned with `(M-2-4.south)`. (3) Yes, I should have said `H` isn't used. Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected above. Sorry for the mistake. `G` is used; `H` is not. Either would do equally well. We just need to find the bottom.